# ArgumentError - A copy of Api::V2 has been removed from the module tree but is still active!:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, activesupport

I must have messed up with my api in some ways. I'm now getting the following error message:

> ArgumentError - A copy of Api::V2 has been removed from the module
>   tree but is still active!:

I'm not sure how to solve this. Some of my Api controllers looks like this:

```
class Api::V2::UsersController < ApplicationController
```

But it used to be like this:

```
module Api
  module V2
    class Api::V2::UsersController < ApplicationController
```

What's the correct format and how can I solve this issue? Thank you.

EDIT:

```
.../active_support/dependencies.rb:457: warning: already initialized constant Api
.../active_support/dependencies.rb:457: warning: previous definition of Api was here

LoadError - Unable to autoload constant Api::UsersController, expected .../app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb to define it:
```

I also have both **api/users_controller.rb** and **api/v2/users_controller.rb** and both seem to have the same issue.

Comment: Did you restart your server / console and Spring

Comment: Please clarify what error do you have now: `ArgumentError` or `LoadError` or both?

Answer (score 1):

In order for `class Api::V2::UsersController < ApplicationController` to work, your folder structure should be `/controllers/api/v2/users_controller.rb` and the `application_controller.rb` file should be under `/controllers`.

Comment: If you restarted spring and rails and still get the error, it means your app still has references to the old version. It is possible you are autoloading something. A complete stack trace would be helpful. Either way, you can try like this: `class ::Api::V2::UsersController < ApplicationController`.

Comment: Thanks but the problem persists.

Comment: After your edit, are you sure the you still version your API?
```LoadError - Unable to autoload constant Api::UsersController, expected .../app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb to define it:```
means it is supposed to be `class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController` under `/controllers/api` and `application_controller.rb` under `/controllers` folder

Comment: Yes, that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby class names' parts divided by `::` are namespaces and should be embraced by `module` keyword, so class `Api::V2::UsersController` should be defined as

```rb
module Api
  module V2
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
#or
class Api::V2::UsersController < ApplicationController
```

and placed, as @MihaiColceriu said, under `/controllers/api/v2/users_controller.rb`

If you have **/controllers/api/users_controller.rb** it should define `Api::UsersController` class

```rb
module Api
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
```

Please pay special attention that class name with namespaces and filename with directories should be consistent and uniquely match each other